# Get posts from facebook user

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm new in Facebook API and i'm looking for php script which can get all posts between two dates and display them in my site. I tried to find information in Facebook developers website but i didn't find what i need. If someone can help me with tutorial or example code it will be great.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way through using FQL. It will return your a number of the most recent posts, I don't know if there is a way to get the posts between 2 specific dates. Try the limit one:

```
$Posts = 'SELECT created_time,message,like_info,type,attachment,share_count from stream WHERE source_id=1234 AND actor_id=1234 LIMIT 50';
$ret_Posts = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query','query' => $Posts));
```

This code will return you as an array the latest 50 posts with the information that is required, you can increase the limit for more posts. For more information check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream